# Batch, How To Read in a Blank Line of Text File

Tags: batch-file, text-files

i need to read in the first line and identify whether it is blank or string of number. If it is blank line, the program will tell this text is invalid then terminate otherwise i will use that string to do further calculation. 
BUT, The code i used is below, it just can not store the blank line such that i can not use if-statement to check whether it is null or "". Any suggestion?

```
   set "text_file=20150629_eleave_i_test.txt"
   :: Get the first six characters of the first line
   set /p first_six=<%text_file%
```

If the text file in the view of notepad++ is

---

```
1
2 00000720150625
```

---

Thank you for advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "blank line"? Is it a line with spaces? How many spaces? Or is it an _empty line_ with no contents? You should post _the real contents_ of the file enclosed in code tags.

Comment: Hi Aacini, It is a complete empty line.
So the file has exact two lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
set "text_file=20150629_eleave_i_test.txt"
set "first_line="
set /p first_line=< %text_file%
if not defined first_line (
   echo This text is invalid
   goto :EOF
)
set "first_six=%first_line:~0,6%"
```

Comment: Yeah, this ans is great and neat. I just don't there is `if not define ()` to use.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think `if not defined first_line ...` is clearer than `if "%first_line%" equ "" ...`, but of course you may use the second form if you wish...

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "ln="
set /p "ln=" <"20150629_eleave_i_test.txt"
if not defined ln (
  echo First line is empty
) else (
  for /f "delims=0123456789" %%A in ("%ln%") do echo First line is not fully numeric
) || echo First line is fully numeric
```